# Can I simulate pressing the Enter key in an Excel macro?

Tags: excel, vba, text-to-speech

I am using an Excel macro to perform a text-to-speech readout of text in a specific cell:

```
Range("$D$10").Select
Application.Speech.SpeakCellOnEnter = True
```

This requires the user to press the Enter key after the macro is called for this to be activated. That means two actions by the user, since the macro is called by the user clicking a "Listen" link on the sheet. Is there a way to simulate the Enter key press within the macro? Or is there a better option for text-to-speech?

Comment: Why not just call the macro that runs when enter is pressed?

Comment: You can use Application.SendKeys "{ENTER}"

Comment: Thank you!! Don't know how I missed Application.SendKeys with all my searching. That did the trick.

Answer (score 7):

Include the Sendkeys in your Macro

```
Application.SendKeys "{ENTER}" 
Range("$D$10").Select
Application.Speech.SpeakCellOnEnter = True
```